# How should I bootstrap my web app using Backbone.Marionette and requireJs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, backbone-routing

Let's say my app works but I love to learn and to find the best way of doing things.
I really appreciate this post about [Reducing Backbone Routers To Nothing More Than Configuration](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/01/02/reducing-backbone-routers-to-nothing-more-than-configuration/).
And the following [bbclonemail](https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail/tree/master/public/javascripts) which is not using requires.

Actually my implementation is a monolithic block (**app.js**, **router.js**).

Here's my questions:
1) What should the `router module` `router.js` return?
2) How should I remove `The Callback Functions` from `router.js` ?
3) What should the `app module` `app.js` return?
4) How should I decouple the `app.js` in many others apps (for example: main, tasks, projects)

---

**app.js**

```
// app.js
define([
'router'
// some modules
],
function (router, Backbone, HeaderView)
{
    "use strict";
    var myApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    myApp.addRegions({
        header: '#header',
        sidebar: '#sidebar',
        mainColumn: '#main-column',
        rightColumn: '#right-column'
    });

    myApp.initHeader = function () {
        var headerView = new HeaderView();
        myApp.header.show(headerView);
    }

    // many others many views

    myApp.start();

    myApp.initialize = function() {
        router.initialize();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    return myApp;

});
```

---

**router.js**

```
// router.js
define([
// some modules
],
function (Backbone)
{
    "use strict";
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

        routes: {
            tasks: 'tasks',
            projects: 'projects',
            // many others  keys/values
            '*defaults': 'home'
        },

        getApp: function ()
        {
            var mainApp;
            require(['js/app'], function (app) {
                mainApp = app;
            });
            return mainApp;
        },

        home: function()
        {
            var app = this.getApp();
            app.initHeader();
            app.initSidebar();
            app.initTaskDetails();
        },

       // many others callbacks

    });

    var initialize = function() {
        new AppRouter;
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Router part you should make like this:

**router.js**

```
// router.js
define([
     'rooterController'
// some modules
],
function (Backbone, rooterController)
{
    "use strict";
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

        routes: {
            tasks: 'tasks',
            projects: 'projects',
            // many others  keys/values
            '*defaults': 'home'
        }
    });
    return new AppRouter({constroller: rooterController})
});
```